# TestNG unable to find the Test class in the Classpath

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

The TestNg is failing to find my Test Class in the Classpath. I am attaching the MAven configuration and the TestNg.xml file.

I have tried clean up the project.This Temporarily fixes the problem.On the subsequent runs, again the same problem.

I have also tried converting the project to TestNG project in the Eclipse.This also fix the issue Temporarily.

**testng.xml file**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
             <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
              <suite name="Suite">
                <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
                     <classes>
                         <class name="com.yodlee.api.tests.TestAPI" />
                     </classes>
               </test> <!-- Test -->
             </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**pom.xml file**

```
                   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**Build Failure Error Logs:**

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.518 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-15T10:51:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/378M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project ysl: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.yodlee.api.tests.TestAPI
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Did you try with `mvn clean package` command ?

Comment: Yes. I do mvn clean package -P warbuild as this is a war

Comment: Looks like testNg.xml is not in the classpath but eclipse is able to find. Can you post the error here ?

Comment: In Maven pom.xml, put the testNg.xml file as configuration so that after compilation, the config file will be copied to test/resources folder.

Comment: @DebadattaMishra Is it not the way I have the Configuration in my pom?

Comment: Check this link and compare accordingly. https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/how-to-execute-testng-tests-with-maven-build/